# Cross domain ajax GET parameters not allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get data from an API with javascript but i'm getting an error on the request.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/",
    type: "GET",
    succes: myfunction
});
```

result:

```
{"error": "GET parameters not allowed for this request."}
```

I use Jsonp because its another domain.
Why can't I get the data with Jquery? 
If I just browse to the link I can see the Json.

Comment: Is it a third party API or have you access to the code?

Comment: Well if i browse to it I can see the json, so i have access because its a public function

Comment: "*Why can't I get the data with Jquery?*" Because the server doesn't appear to support/allow JSONP requests. Server applications have to opt-in to both support both/either JSONP and CORS. They aren't automatic or guaranteed. And, if a server hasn't opted into either, cross-domain Ajax requests aren't possible.

Comment: So they only support Json, how can I get the data with Json from a cross domain?

Comment: @Freddy If CORS isn't supported either, you may have to create a server-side proxy on your own origin to make the request to `bitstamp.net` for the client and report back the response.

Comment: If you want to use PHP I can provide you the PHP code you can use to access this API

Comment: Thanks but I'm using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried getting data from the url you provided using AJAX. The server did not return any data using the `$.ajax` and this clearly shows that the server **does not support cross domain requests.** That is why I asked you if you had access to code because you have to manually specify if you want API to support cross domain requests.

One way around to this is using some server side language to access this API. I once had similar problem and the used **PHP CURL** to access the API. The php code then served data to JQuery to be used on frontend. So you can write relay code to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as the error message says, bitstamp do not allow it.

If they get a JSONP request for the data, they respond with the error instead of the normal response.

Comment: So they won't let me get the data by jsonp, is there another way to read this data?

Comment: @Freddy use some relay code on the server side to get data from this link.