# How to connect to a https websocket with Dart?

Tags: websocket, dart

I'm trying to connect to Bitstamp streaming api and it seems that their (unofficial) docs only mention `https` protocol. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```dart
var ws = new WebSocket('https://websocket.bitstamp.net:8080'); 
ws.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e) {
  print('Received message: ${e.data}');
});
```

however, this results in *Internal Dartium error*. If I try to connect using `ws://` instead, then everything looks fine (no errors), but I don't get any messages from the socket. Where do you think the problem might be? Could it be the Bitstamp API issue and not really a Dart problem?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I used `wss://`. However still nothing is received from Bitstamp. I guess it's their API issue I'd have to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Bitstamp does not support cross domain requests. As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078305/cross-domain-ajax-get-parameters-not-allowed), you may be able to write some server side code to get the request and then relay it to client side.

Here's a little more info on [CORS in dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/#a-note-on-cors-and-httprequest), although I think the JS interop code is dated.

Comment: Your answer is a little irrelevant. I was talking about Websockets. Websockets don't care about domains. Bitstamp, apart from the official REST API also has a Websocket streaming API which works through Pusher. I ended up using Pusher's js app through `dart:js`.